# Searching file only working once

Tags: python, arrays, file, python-2.7, loops

I have this code:

```
import linecache
car=1
vehical=[]
for x in range (7): #run this 7 times
    car=car+3 #number plates are on every 3rd line
    to_add=linecache.getline('finesV2.txt', car) #take the line (car variable contains integer concerning which one)
    vehical.append(to_add) #add this to array
file = open("details.txt", "r")
car=0
for x in range (7): #run this 7 times
    searchfor=vehical[car][0:7] #load time to search file for
    print "searchfor",searchfor #for debugging
    for line in file: #run amount of lines that are in the file
        if searchfor in line: #check if item being searched for is in that line
            print line #print out the line
    car=car+1 #increase the car variable to search for next item in vehicle array on next run
file.close()
```

This program outputs the following:

```
searchfor GX99QME
GX99QME,Alex 123,test street

searchfor IL45LTQ
searchfor ZX46GSR
searchfor GN11ILW
searchfor IN82SSD
searchfor WE50JEY
searchfor QS26DLO
```

However what I want and expect the program to do is search the file for each of the number plates to load the drivers details. I have confirmed that the search function is working and that the number plates are correct in the file I am searching in because if line 14 is changed to:

```
if "IL45LTQ" in line:
```

then the program returns:

```
searchfor GX99QME
IL45LTQ,Tom

searchfor IL45LTQ
searchfor ZX46GSR
searchfor GN11ILW
searchfor IN82SSD
searchfor WE50JEY
searchfor QS26DLO
```

Ideally what I want is the program to return the details for all of the number plates. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some further research it turns out read doesn't jump back to the start and I had to add file.seek(0) to reset it back to the top of the file.